# JPA annotation to save id of an object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following bean

```
@Entity
public class A {
   @id
   @generatedvalue
   int id;
   @Column(name="FIELD1")
   private string field1;

   @Autowired
   private MyType field2;

   //getters and setters
}
```

I also have a DAO class to access this bean. The application has a database with a table A and 2 fields, field1 and field2. The value that is stored in field2 in the database should be an id of field2, I can ask this via

> field2.getId();

How should I annotate this in JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA shouldn't be using dependency injection annotations like `@Autowired`. Instead, it seems that what you want is a [many-to-one foreign-key relationship](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html) (or perhaps just a one-to-one, if `field2` can only be associated with one `A`). Annotate it like this:

```
@ManyToOne
private MyType field2;
```